# Using switch statement in transform

Tags: r, switch-statement

I have a data frame with :

```
    Exposure Signal  Noise ill ADC
201     0.01  185.0 0.6744   1  12
471     0.03  210.2 0.7683   4  12
101     0.01  218.2 0.8356   1  10
381     0.03  249.5 0.8609   4  10
1       0.01  258.4 0.8988   1   9
301     0.03  292.7 0.8326   4   9
```

where I want to multiply Exposure by a factor depending on the `ill` value, the latter being either 1, 4 or 10.

I tried the following:

```
df2 <- transform(df, Exposure = Exposure * switch ("ill", "1"=1, "4"=3, "10"=11.5)  )
```

But all I get is NAs in `df2$Exposure`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned , `switch` is not vectorized, Another option is to use `ifelse` (even it is not really simple to  write nested `ifelse`):

```
df2 <- transform(df, 
        Exposure = Exposure * ifelse(ill== 1,1,
                                     ifelse(ill==4,3,
                                            ifelse(ill==10,11.5,1))))
```

#### edit add a vectorized switch function

This is a first attempt to create a "vectorized switch" function ( the code is only tested in the OP case) :

```
switch_v <-
  function(expr,...){
    cond <- list(...)
    lefts <- as.numeric(names(cond))
    values <- cond
    for(i in seq_along(lefts))
       expr[expr==lefts[i]] <- values[i]
    unlist(expr)
  }
```

Now you can use it as normal `switch`:

```
df <- transform(df, 
                 Exposure2 = Exposure * switch_v(ill,"1"=1, "4"=3, "10"=11.5))
```

Comment: Thanks! Not too ugly, although a real switch would be much cleaner

Answer (score 3):

`switch` isn't the right thing here - you need something that is vectorised for all values of `ill`. What you've got is something that operates on the character value "ill" - its not looking at your data frame at all there!

Clues to this include:

```
> switch ("ill", "1"=1, "4"=3, "10"=11.5)
>
```

returns nothing...

```
> switch (df$ill, "1"=1, "4"=3, "10"=11.5)
Error in switch(df$ill, `1` = 1, `4` = 3, `10` = 11.5) : 
  EXPR must be a length 1 vector
```

errors because you fed it a vector.

I'd create a lookup table for your multiplications:

```
> map=data.frame(ill=c(1,4,10), factor=c(1,3,11.5))
> map
  ill factor
1   1    1.0
2   4    3.0
3  10   11.5
```

Then use a `dplyr` inner join to get the factor for each row:

```
> require(dplyr)
> df %>% inner_join(map)
Joining by: "ill"
    Exposure ill factor
1  0.3698771   4    3.0
2  0.4274825   4    3.0
3  0.4120654   1    1.0
4  0.3098392   4    3.0
5  0.3205585   4    3.0
6  0.5340227  10   11.5
7  0.6466888  10   11.5
8  0.1581114  10   11.5
9  0.2598404   1    1.0
10 0.3056725   4    3.0
```

Then add a mutate and a select to get back what you want:

```
> df %>% inner_join(map) %>% mutate(Exposure=Exposure*factor) %>% select(-factor)
Joining by: "ill"
    Exposure ill
1  1.1096313   4
2  1.2824476   4
3  0.4120654   1
4  0.9295175   4
5  0.9616755   4
6  6.1412607  10
7  7.4369216  10
8  1.8182816  10
9  0.2598404   1
10 0.9170176   4
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however I find agstudy's solution cleaner

Comment: @CharlesB maybe cleaner here , but if you have more conditions , I would also use a lookup table (like the answer exposed here but using dplyr).

Comment: You'll not be saying that when you have twenty values in your lookup table and the indenting is going into the next room! :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `switch` or `ifelse`:

```
transform(df, Exposure = Exposure * c(1, 3, 11.5)[ill / 4 + 1])
```

*How it works?*

The command `ill / 4 + 1` returns `1.25` if `ill == 1`, `2.0` if `ill == 4`, and `3.5` if `ill == 10`.
These values are used for indexing (`[]`). Therefore, they are automatically cast to integers, i.e., `1`, `2`, and `3`. These indices are used to select the appropriate values from the vector `c(1, 3, 11.5)`.

Comment: but if you do that you need a serious comment in your code to explain what its doing! #fragile

Comment: A similar trick would be to convert the `ill` number to a factor, and then convert to numeric, and then indexing - hence "1" becomes 1, "4" becomes 2, and "10" becomes 3 (as long as the factor levels are in that order).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is to use `sapply`

```
df2 <- transform (df, Exposure = Exposure * sapply(as.character(ill), switch, "1" = 1, "4"=3, "10" = 11.5))
```